# show/hide div jquery not working in fixed position

Tags: jquery, css

show/hide `div` using jquery not working when the `div` `wrapper` is `position:fixed` but if, Change into `position:relative` the show/hide `div` back to work.

here is the **[fiddle of position:relative](http://jsfiddle.net/HYjEB/1221/)**

and this is the [**fiddle of position:fixed**](http://jsfiddle.net/HYjEB/1222/) the the `div` `show/hide` is not showing.

```
var flag = 0;
var leftValue;
$('#button').on('click',function(){
      flag = !flag;
      leftValue = flag ? 100 : 0;
        $('#right').animate({ left: leftValue }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#button').text(function(i,v){
           return v == 'Close' ? 'Menu' : 'Close';
         });
        });
    });

/* show/hide DIV when passed the other div */
       $(document).scroll(function(){
       var vis = ($(document).scrollTop() > ($('.passedMe').offset().top+$('.passedMe').height()));
       $('.showHide').css('display', vis?'':'none')
       });
      /* show/hide DIV when passed the other div */
```

have anyone have an idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because your code here

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
```

so your `scroll function` will work if you're scrolling the `document` or `body`, but because you use `position: fixed`, there's no `scrollbar` in the `body`, but the `scrollbar` is in the

```
<div id="right">
    ...
</div>
```

this make the `scroll function` never called, so you need to change

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    ...
});
```

to

```
$("#right").scroll(function(){    // Depend on the container that use the position: fixed;
    ...
});
```

here's the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYjEB/1223/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `fixed` position is automatically set `left` and `top` `0` but `relative` position set to the relative of parent tag.

Setting the below css should do the trick:

```
top:20px
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `#right{position: relative/fixed }` has influence to the behavior.

`position: fixed`: The element is positioned relative to the browser window.

`position: relative`: The element is positioned relative to its normal position.

Answer (score 0):

Bind scroll to your `div#right`

```
$("#right").scroll(function () {
    console.log("scrolling")
    var vis = ($(document).scrollTop() > ($('.passedMe').offset().top + $('.passedMe').height()));
     $('.showHide').css('display', vis?'':'none')
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HYjEB/1225/)